# Go to default url when pressing start in iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm using MVC-4. After I copy the files and paste them into the server,in IIS I right press on  "Sites" then choose "Restart" to start the project again. But the project run only if I explicitly write the url in the browser...

Or in another words, I have a log document that each function writes to it the name of the function. (current function), and in `Global.asax.cs` I have this:

> routes.MapRoute(
>
> ```
>             "Default",
>             "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
>             new { controller = "boxes", action = "FillList", id = UrlParameter.Optional} 
>         );
> ```

When I write the base url, I see this function name in the log file, but not when I press "Restart", then it doesn't get to this function.
Is there an option to run it once I choose "Restart"?

(I need it because another project uses it to pass the list from here)

Comment: I don't understand why you want your application to start at IIS start. You should not reference IIS application but with URL and when you do that it'll start. What's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the default document for your site in IIS.